# What does OBJECT_ID do in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, object-identity

I'm trying out the usage of `OBJECT_ID` and found [the following entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx) in MSDN:

> *"Returns the database object identification number of a schema-scoped object."*

What is database object identification number and what is schema scoped object. Seems like I'm more confused than initial.

Answer (score 4):

The `OBJECT_ID` is used to identify the object uniquely in the system base tables.

It is the primary key of the `sys.sysschobjs` base table used by the  `sys.objects` metadata view and appears in many other of the metadata views. e.g `sys.partitions`. If you aren't querying these views then the `object_id` isn't very useful except perhaps when using in a check for object existence as below.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('T', 'U') IS NULL
     /*Table T does not exist or no permissions*/
```

A schema scoped object is one that belongs to a schema (e.g a table, view, stored procedure). The MSDN article gives an example of a non schema scoped object in DDL triggers.

It is an error to try and specify a schema when creating these

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SomeTrigger /*Will Fail*/
ON DATABASE 
FOR DROP_SYNONYM
AS 
PRINT 'SomeTrigger'
```

Non schema scoped objects metadata is still stored in `sys.sysschobjs` but does not show up in the `sys.objects` view.